# SSRS 2016 compatibility with SQL 2017 after SQL2016 upgrade

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, upgrade, ssrs-2016

We have an SQL Server database engine on the 2016 version. We also have SSRS in the 2016 version. I plan to upgrade the SQL database engine from the 2016 version to the 2017 for it to participate in AG with the 2017 database server.

After SQL Database engine upgrades from 2016 to 2017(that has SSRS reporting databases), will SQL 2016 SSRS connect to upgraded SQL 2017 with no issues? We plan to take VM snapshot of the box with SQL 2016 server installed.

Comment: So you are going to do in-place upgrade the instance with ReportServer database?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: I don't see any issue in this approach other than I don't like in-place upgrade.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your reply